# best ide for javascript dev - dojo is my target

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

what do people use when working with complicated framework -  dojo , jquery etc

vs2008 plus ie has nice debugging

plain editor plus firebug is ok

but what about intellisense, are there any editors that can deal with these complex frameworks

any other 'must have' tools

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at

[Aptana](http://aptana.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard people reference [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/), [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) as good solutions, but I've always just used [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not [Ruby Mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) is a great IDE for Javascript. I work in a .Net shop and we use VS2008 + Rubymine and we don't do any Ruby development whatsoever.

Comment: Agreed. RubyMine uses exactly the same codebase as IntelliJ IDEA for its JavaScript handling and it's the best I've come across.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have been using [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/), a free editor.

Searching in the Tools, Add-Ons menu for Dojo should bring up a Dojo API Catalogs extension that allows for intellisense of Dojo APIs.

Answer (score 1):

At JetBrains we've just developed lightweight [HTML/JS editor WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) that includes very smart JavaScript Editor. It supports jQuery, YUI, HTML5 API and allows to debug your JS right from IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) for all my web development.  It's free, has a ton of plugins, and does everything I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is good for PHP or if you do ASP.NET then VS 2008. 
I think both has good support for Javascript. 
Aptana is also good. 
Dreamweaver CS4 is ok, but not great.

Answer (score 0):

I second Aptana, I use it in eclipse as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has intellsence for JavaScript and Dojo, Aptana does too. But my personal preference is Netbeans.

Answer (score -1):

Scott Gu explains [how to get intellisense for JQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) inside Visual Studio 2008.

Share and enjoy :)

Dan

Comment: totally cool for jquery - not for dojo. I suppose I just need to create the vsdoc file for dojo (unless somebody already did it?)